# Large volume mails with Google apps

Tags: google-apps

My web application is hosted on IIS7. Google Apps has been working great for my SMTP needs. Now that I have a fairly large userbase along with a forum, there are many email notices being sent daily.

Google Apps has a limit on 500 emails per 24 hours per smtp user, which sometimes cause a conflict with my needs.

In an attempt to fix this, I created 4 google app users to rotate the load and set up an SQL job every 8 hours to change the HostSettings data for SMTPUsername.

Also I'm concerned about sending monthly newsletters now because I have about 40K users and obviously this is a nightmare to do with Google Apps.

I don't want to use SmarterMail provided by my ISP because google apps is very easy to administer.

Can you please give me a solution to overcome this? Whether relay SMTP server solves this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you talked with Google about this?  Since you have such a huge user base, it sounds like you may be able to pay money to receive more "unlimited" support.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an infrastructure question, and I'm not 100% sure, but I'd guess that creating multiple accounts *just* for mass mailing is probably against the terms of service of your Google apps account.

Answer (score 0):

Creating multiple accounts is allowed. However, Google Apps is generally not meant to be a bulk message sending tool so you're going to face some pain using it instead of paying for a service that is designed for bulk sending.

You might consider upgrading to Google Apps for Business. This will bump your per user daily sending limit to 2,000 messages / day.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852

Jay